# emacs doesn't displays Rd files content in package development

Tags: r, emacs, devtools, roxygen2, ess

I make R package development in **emacs** by the help of the devtools (and roxygen2) package to create Rd files and display them by `?function_name`. Normal workflow:

- write functions in R files
- call `devtools::load_all()` and `devtools::document()`
- call `?function_name` to display formatted Rd content

Rd files are created. NAMESPACE is updated. With my old system in emacs and with the new system in a shell the formatted Rd content is displayd. But if I do the same in my new system in emacs I get now the error message:

> Can’t find documentation for ‘function_name‘

Any hints to fix the problem?

My new system:

- MX-Linux 21.2.1 KDE_x64 Wildflower
- emacs 27.1
- ess 18.10.3snapshot (ess-20220915.2126 installed over elpa)
- devtools 2.4.4
- roxygen2 7.2.1